# Include() not working when Select new object in Entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

My code:

```
DbContext.Musics()
         .Include(m => m.Author)
         .Select(m => new MyComplexType()
         {
                MyMusic = m,
                blablabla = ...
         })
```

The result MyComplexType.MyMusic.Author is null, I don't know how to solve it...

Comment: please also post the configuration of your model classes

Comment: Please, could you add more information? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Then `m.Author` is `null`. This specific record doesn't have an `AuthorID`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue in EF6 and prior, you can see a bug report in EF at 
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/599

The behavior has been updated to allow `Include(...)` into projections as of EF7-beta4, however for EF 6 or previous, this bug remains.

Comment: Your link shows it is not a bug. It was not designed to work in EF6. It works in EF7 and is now supported but that does not make it a bug in EF6.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to do as you describe. When you select another type (not that type for which you did Include), Include no longer loads related entities, as you noticed yourself. Easy way to achieve what you want is:

```
DbContext.Musics()         
     .Select(m => new MyComplexType()
     {
            MyMusic = m,
            Author = m.Author,
            blablabla = ...
     })
```

Update to asnwer complains from comments. Using author's code (and settings EnableLazyLoading to off on EF context), you will see that MyComplexType.MyMusic.Author is always null, even if Author is really in database. So Include does not work (does not do what you are expecting it to) in this particual case.

In code included in my answer, MyComplexType.Author will be correctly loaded (no need to use any Includes). So it's quite not the same as author's code.

Comment: What is _"When you select another type Include no longer loads related entities"_ supposed to mean? It's not true.

Comment: I completely do not understand what your answer changes. If `Author` is eagerly loaded, this property is going to be null in your solution.

Comment: Updated answer with response to your comments.